# Set Wallpaper Across Multiple Screens Mac Java (Have Example Obj-C Code)

Tags: java, objective-c

I am trying to relearn code after a year or so of being inactive and I'm attempting to morph some old Objective-C code I wrote into Java. I'm trying to set the wallpaper for multiple screens, and allow the user to customize which screens have what wallpaper etc (so some could be the same, 1 might be different, etc). I know Objective-C can handle this no problem but I can't seem to get Java to.

Objective-C code:

```
 for (NSScreen *screen in [NSScreen screens]) {
        NSURL *imageURL = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] desktopImageURLForScreen:[[NSScreen screens] lastObject]];
        NSLog(@"Current Wallpaper URL: %@",imageURL);

        NSString* aString = [NSString stringWithString:[@"~/desktop/receivedImage.jpeg"stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
        NSLog(@"Wallpaper to-be location as String: %@",aString);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:aString];
        NSLog(@"Wallpaper to-be location as URL: %@",url);

        [sws setDesktopImageURL:url forScreen:screen options:nil error:&err];

        imageURL = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] desktopImageURLForScreen:screen];
        NSLog(@"New URL: %@",imageURL);
        if(err != nil)
            NSLog(@"%@",err);
    }
```

If you could point me to a resource or directory as well as an answer that would be great as this is a learning exercise for me.

Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: You could try searching for JNA

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [roCocoa](https://code.google.com/p/rococoa/)